# Which exception should I throw when building cache fail?

Tags: java, exception

I have a class that contains a cache (Set), and the cache is built on instantiation. I'm confused which exception/error should I throw if building cache fail (cannot connect to database or some).

```
class Provider {

   public Provider() {
       buildCache();
   }

   private void buildCache() {
       try {
           this.cache = getDataFromDb();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new ???
       }          
   }
}
```

One exception comes in my mind is `ExceptionInInitializerError`, but javadoc says it is thrown on initialize static members.

Should I throw an `IllegalStateException` cause the cache isn't built so this class is useless?

Clearly I can create my own `ErrorOnBuildingCache` and throw it but I wonder if any exception in Java library suits this circumstance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If **you're** in doubt as to which exception should be thrown, then so will users of your code.  So define your own exception type (e.g. `FailedToInitializeCacheException`) and throw that. No ambiguity that way.

`IllegalStateException` would be a reasonable fallback position, but you should never, ever use `ExceptionInInitializerError` (or anything ending in `Error`) - that's low-level classloader stuff, don't mess with that.

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly I can create my own
>   ErrorOnBuildingCache and throw it but
>   I wonder if any exception in Java
>   library suits this circumstance.

This is exactly what you should do. Do not try to use an existing exception, but instead make one of your own. So you know when it is throwed that it is related to your cache and not a static field instanciation error or something.

On a side note, you shouldn't catch exception excepted in very specific cases. Catching exception will catch everything like null pointer exceptions, divide by zero, IO errors, security exception.

What I would do is:

- Include the cause when rethrowing the
  exception to allow better
  investigation
- Catch exceptions that could occurs
  due to IO/Network problems but
  associate them with the right error
  message. In you case this is DB exceptions.
- Do not catch exception that are due
  to programming bugs (like null
  pointers), let them popup so you
  directly know the real error cause.